# C# Finding the Inverse of a Func

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a math function stored inside a Func<T,TResult> delegate, (this could be any math function)

```
private Func<float, float> function => (x) => x * x;
```

In order to get an output for a specific input I just have a method that evaluates the expression

```
public float Evaluate(float x) {
    return function(x);
}
```

Is there a way that I could inversely evaluate that function?

For example, in math the inverse of `f(x)` is just `f⁻¹(x)`. Is there a way to find `f⁻¹(x)` programmatically?

The only thing that I have tried is to of course just store in the inverse of that function in another Func delegate, in this case

```
private Func<float, float> inverseFunction => (y) => Math.Sqrt(y);
```

And that would be really annoying since I have to manually find the inverse of the function everytime

Comment: I think in several functions that can be inversed, just depends on how you programming and what the function is doing. This question is opinion based, or you should focus your question in only one function.

Comment: Even with mathematics there is no way to do this. In maths we have a way of notating the inverse of a function, but there's no universal way to compute the inverse of a function. What you're asking for doesn't make sense if you're trying to ground it in mathematics.

Comment: _find the inverse of the function everytime_ Well, not even that is always possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `functions` in many languages, including C#, don't always satisfy the rules of functions in mathematics. They don't always produce the same output for a given input, and they can cause side effects. As a result, there's not a way to find the "inverse" of a method or `Func` in C#.